# How do I use the changes feed in a sync algorithm?

Tags: google-drive-api

I understand how I can use fetch the changes feed to list changes since the last fetch.

What I don't understand is how to incorporate this into a bi-directional sync algorithm.
Specifically, how do I exclude my own changes from a subsequent fetch.

For example my sync does:-
Phase 1. I fetch server changes. Let's say there are none
Phase 2. I upload my local changes. Say a new file called NewFile

Some time later I sync again, and phase 1 includes NewFile as a change. Therefore NewFile gets round tripped.

I considered adding a phase 3 which repeats the fetch changes in order to advance the ChangeId and ignore those. The problem is that it is possible that another client was making updates during phase 2.

Answer (score 2):

There is additional information you can use to test whether a file has changed, like the checksum, or etag for the entry, depending on whether you care about the file data, or the metadata too.

You should integrate this into your syncing algorithm so you don't get the race condition you talk about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 

Can you comment on the stability/lifecycle of md5checksum and etag?

I've had issues in the past where the etag returned in the Files resource of the response to an Update is short lived, ie. a few seconds after my update, the etag changes. I'm guessing this is caused by asynchronous processing that is taking place on the uploaded content. I'm guessing the same issue will apply to md5checksum since both my uploads and downloads have convert=true.